# Azure servicebus messages when webapp scale out to fewer instances

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

What happens if you have let's say 4 instances of a webapp, and a lot of messages queued up in the service bus queue (meant to reach all the 4 instances) and the webapp scales down to only 2 instances. Will the messages, in the service bus that were meant for the other two instances that were removed, be stuck in the queue until the time to live is exceeded and then removed or does the service bus understand that there are not 4 instances anymore and therefore it doesn't need to send out messages to 4 instances?

I'm not sure if this is the correct but from my understanding there usually is a topic and then multiple subscriptions? will the service bus understand when one of the instances (who has a subscription) is gone and then removes the message meant for that subscription while the message is queued up (a lot of other messages before it)?

Sorry if the question is a little dumb but I couldn't find any answers on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

> Will the messages, in the service bus that were meant for the other two instances that were removed, be stuck in the queue until the time to live is exceeded and then removed

Service Bus queues and topic subscriptions provide a secondary sub-queue, called a dead-letter queue (DLQ).
The purpose of the dead-letter queue is to hold messages that cannot be delivered to any receiver, or simply messages that could not be processed. More details please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues).

> does the service bus understand that there are not 4 instances anymore and therefore it doesn't need to send out messages to 4 instances?

Service Bus Queues offer First In, First Out (FIFO) message and Service Bus queue  message is received and processed by only one message consumer. If we have multiple  web instance, when a quest arrive then WebApp LoadBlance ([ARR](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/disabling-arrs-instance-affinity-in-windows-azure-web-sites/)) will assign  the request to the corresponding instance to process the message. If the instance has been removed, the WebApp loadBlance ([ARR](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/disabling-arrs-instance-affinity-in-windows-azure-web-sites/)) will assign the request to the existing instance.

> will the service bus understand when one of the instances (who has a subscription) is gone and then removes the message meant for that subscription while the message is queued up (a lot of other messages before it)?

As mentioned above, it is assigned by WebApp LoadBlance not Service bus. How to consume message is depended on your WebApp.